# How to use apt-cache server in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server, apt, apt-cache

I have tried this [Apt-cache server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) on ubuntu 10.10, and it worked.
But, now i'm using ubuntu 12.04 and all tutorial inside that page not working for me :

```
Ign http://136.198.117.4 precise/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://136.198.117.4:3142/id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
```